# repeat .shift() if it extracts a nan value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to understand what shift() does when it returns an nan value.

Example df:

```
   index a   b
    1    2   3
    2    3   3
    3    nan nan
    4    8   7
```

If I type:

```
for i in range(2,5)
    df["a"] = np.where((df.index==i), df.b * df.a.shift(1), df.a)
```

I guess (but am not sure) it will return:

```
    index a   b 
      1   2   3 
      2   6   3 
      3   nan nan
      4   8   7
```

Is there a simple way that it will return:

```
     index a   b 
      1    2   3 
      2    6   3 
      3   nan  nan
      4    42  7
```

with the 42 in column "a" row 4 calculated as 6*7 (column "a" row 2 multiplied by column "b" row 4)
What I want is that if the value extracted with shift(1) is nan, the function takes the value one row above as if I typed shift(2). If there is a nan value in this cell again, it should take the value in the cell above, as if I typed shift(3) and so on.

Comment: What you want to achieve is really unclear. Please update your question to improve clarity.

Comment: Yes, add `ffill()` to extend that previous non-NaN value to NaN spaces. `df["a"] = np.where((df.index==i), df.b * df.a.shift(1).ffill(), df.a) `.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I was looking for!